# In Visual Studio my method name is colored Blue instead of White

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I cannot figure out why the method names are colored dark blue instead of white. Below is my code, the problem is the `Update()` method name:

[image: This is my code. The problem is the "void Update()".]

Comment: Note that it's also possible to [change fonts and colors in the editor in Visual Studio settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165337.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

There is no problem, that's a special integration made when you work with Unity inside Visual Studio.

Normally, besides turning the method names blue, you should also see IntelliSense for `MonoBehaviour` methods (like `Start`, `Update`, `Awake`, etc).